# Vim autocommand based on username - print message

Tags: vimrc, vimscript, autocmd

I have a function in my bashrc that checks if a file is writable with `[ -w "$1" ]`. If it is, I open it with vim normally. If it's not, I open with sudo via `sudo env HOME="$HOME" vim -u ~/.vimrc "$1"` to make sure vim sources my `.vimrc` and colorscheme correctly. I want to print a warning message on the message line (whatever that line is called) when I do this, so I know I've had to use sudo. I wrote a vimrc function to display the message how I want:

```
"sudo warning label:
function! Sudowarn ()
  hi TempColor ctermfg=255 ctermbg=88
  echohl TempColor
  echo "Automatically sudo'd to have write access!"
  echohl None
endfunction
```

My problem is that I don't know how to call this function when the file loads only when I've sudo'd. I know vim knows about the `$USER` variable ("root" when sudo'd, "jeremysprofile" when not), and I know `autocmd` has a [User option](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html#User) but I don't know how to use these to solve my problem.

If someone can at least tell me what I should be doing to solve my problem instead of asking internet questions, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: IIRC sudo sets the `SUDO_USER` environment variable, as well as some others. Try `env | grep SUDO`. You can access all environment variables from Vim with `$VARNAME`. I'm sure I answered this question (or something very similar) before in more detail, but I can't find it right now :-(

Comment: @MartinTournoij, `$USER` works as I want, i.e., `:echom $USER` gives "root" when I've used sudo and my username otherwise. I just don't know how to use that in an autocmd =(

Comment: You can just use `if`, right? `autocmd BufRead * if $USER == "root" | call Sudowarn() | endif` (Arguably better to put that `if` in the `Sudowarn()` function though) Or am I misunderstanding what you mean?

Comment: ...oh. No, that's pretty much it. Is there any way to have that message appear and not block the file appearing? With that (or `BufReadPost`) the file contents don't appear until after I've hit enter; the messages seems to block that.

Comment: @MartinTournoij, figured it out; had to change `cmdheight` settings. if you want to post an answer, I'll accept it, otherwise I'll post an answer tomorrow.

Comment: Is there any reason not to use `sudoedit` in your function, btw?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble, sudoedit as in the bash command that takes from `$SUDO_EDITOR`? How would I make it use my `.vimrc` and `.vim/colors`? And how would I use that in my vim function?

Comment: Idk about your vim function, but iirc it automatically uses the proper home directory etc.; effectively, you edit a tmp file with a copy of the original as yourself, and then on write it copies the tmp to the proper location.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble, I just tried `export SUDO_EDITOR=/usr/bin/vim; sudoedit ./file.txt` and it did not source my `~/.vimrc` and didn't have any syntax highlighting.

Comment: Ive never had to set SUDO_EDIT but ive also never had that problem. Hm.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble, `sudoedit` doesn't seem to work properly on CentOS 7 or Ubuntu 16.04, whether or not I've set `SUDO_EDITOR`. What I have now works fine.

Comment: Inconvenient :P works find on ubuntu 18.04. Is EDITOR set?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble, I was using it wrong on ubuntu. It works like you said, but not on CentOS 7. I primarily use CentOS so I will stick with what I have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use the `VimEnter` autocommand and move the conditional inside the function, i.e.

```
augroup vimrc
  autocmd!
  autocmd VimEnter * call SudoWarn()
augroup END

function! SudoWarn()
  if $USER !=# 'root' | return | endif
  ...
endfunction
```

This also moves the autocommand inside an autocommand group; "vimrc" is just an example name, it could be anything. The `autocmd!` will remove all previous autocommands in this group, which is sensible if you should load the vimrc file multiple times.

Note, with this approach, I don't think you need to change the `cmdheight` option, since the `echo` is issued at a later time.

Comment: What is the benefit of having the if statement in the function vs the autocmd? I know how autocmd groups and `!` overwriting work, but so far I haven't found them necessary.

Answer (score 3):

As @Martin pointed out, the `autocmd` was a simple if statement. I didn't realize `autocmd` could do do if or read variables the way `echom` could. I also added `cmdheight` so that the message would not block displaying the file

```
"sudo warning label:
function! Sudowarn ()
  "cmdheight prevents vim from forcing 'push ENTER to continue'
  set cmdheight=2
  hi SudoColor ctermfg=255 ctermbg=88
  echohl SudoColor
  echo "Automatically sudo'd to have write access!"
  echohl None
  set cmdheight=1
endfunction
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead * if $USER == "root" | call Sudowarn() | endif
```